# How sleep eats CPU php

Tags: php, performance

**How is sleep using cpu resources?**

Does it use 100% or 0% of cpu when you sleep your script. Can you explain?

As far as i know it increases load average, but how does it use CPU?

Comment: This is _so_ simple to test. Two consoles: one with your script in, the other with `htop` or `top` or whatever in it. Why haven't you tried that?

Comment: See for yourself https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#L4436

Comment: If the reason you're asking is that you've used a CPU profiler on it, here's what typically happens. You have a little program that enters a sleep for 10 seconds, say. So its wall-clock time is 10 seconds. However, the amount of CPU needed to do that might have been about 1 microsecond, of which 990 nanoseconds could be spent going into and coming out of sleep. So of the tiny bit of CPU time that's used, it's 99% in sleep. This confuses lots of people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way that `sleep` works is OS-dependent, because the PHP function `sleep` [calls into the appropriate runtime function](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#4436) to actually do what it says on the tin.

[For Windows](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/main/win95nt.h#50), that function is [`SleepEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [For other operating systems](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/main/php.h#266) it is the POSIX function `sleep`. In both cases, the documentation for those functions clearly states that the sleeping thread is ineligible for running during the sleep period and therefore cannot consume CPU resources even if it wanted to.

Comment: Can you also post links to those documentations?

Comment: In the linux case, the process doesn't consume CPU: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/do-sleeping-processes-get-the-same-cpu-time/22887